# identityserver on multiple URLs

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4

I have 2 sites. siteA.com and siteB.com, both resolved to the same IIS application. 
Identityserver is abailable on siteA.com/Login, I set it up like this:

```
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "oidc",
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

        Authority = siteA.com/Login,
        ...
    }
```

so if I go to siteB.com, it also redirects me to siteA.com/Login.

I can't use HttpContext.Current.Request here, because it returns local ip address, as this code runs once, setting up the middleware.

Can I somehow redirect from siteA.com to siteA.com/login, and from siteB.com to siteB.com/Login?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.net Core 2 enable multi tenancy using Identity Server 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231697/asp-net-core-2-enable-multi-tenancy-using-identity-server-4)

Comment: hu @RuardvanElburg
thank you for your answer, this actually solved half the problem
So the first problem is, when I visit siteB.com, it redirect me to "shared-domain-for-every-tenant"
The other problem was that even though after I changed the URL manually, it didn't log me in, but IssuerUri solved it :)

Comment: You may want to investigate events. But I'm not sure if that will help and if you can use them in this version. It seems that you are still on asp.net core 1.1. Please note that the code is obsolete and there have been breaking changes.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Half of the code is .net core 2.2, where I haven't tried to make this change yet, and the other half is old .NET, where I am trying to make it work

Comment: That's fine, just note that this may limit the options to answer this question. As I said, do take a look at events (as part of the handler). You may be able to intercept and change the url before doing the actual request.