# Defining the Authority

Tags: identityserver4

Currently I'm doing the following

```
 services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {

                options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer:Authority");
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("IdentityServer:RequireHttps");
                options.ApiName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer:UserManagementApi:ResourceName");
                options.SaveToken = true;
            })
        .AddCookie(cfg => cfg.SlidingExpiration = true);
```

Where I'm getting the Authority from the config file. However, we are upgrading our app to be multi-tenant and need to set these values depending on the tenant being called. Is it possible to set these values from a service that will find the tenant at runtime using IOC.

We are using Dotnet Code 2.2 and Lamar IOC.

There is what appears to be a duplicate of this, however, I have the following issue as we are running a number of microservices.

- Each Tenant has it's own IdentityServer4 tenant, that uses it's own database. This is a standalone service to manage the users.
- Each Api uses it's own tenanted IdentityServer api to authenticate.

So

Api Site ----> connects to IdentityServer4 Site

eg.

```
api1.company1.com connects to auth.company1.com to authenticate
api2.company1.com connects to auth.company1.com to authenticate

api1.company2.com connects to auth.company2.com to authenticate
api2.company2.com connects to auth.company2.com to authenticate
```

Each Api will call other api's and pass the user token on to authenticate. I need a way to tell the api what auth to use to authenticate. Using a shared Authority, when getting the token you get the following

```
{
  "nbf": 1556619889,
  "exp": 1556623489,
  "iss": "http://shared-domain-for-every-tenant,
  "aud": [
    "http://shared-domain-for-every-tenant/resources",
    "api1",
    "api2"
  ],
  "client_id": "postman",
  "scope": [
    "api1",
    "api1"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.net Core 2 enable multi tenancy using Identity Server 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231697/asp-net-core-2-enable-multi-tenancy-using-identity-server-4)

Comment: That helps but not fully, I have expanded my question with a bit more info

Comment: Why is this different than the link Ruard posted? Because you have different instances of IdentityServer4 runnung?

Comment: Each tenant of the IdentityServer has it's own database. So the Authority needs to be set for each tenant. Due to the Authority being the same, when it calls that authority to confirm that the token is valid, it does not exist in the database